# Scale polygon relative to the center

Tags: python, numpy, math

I have numpy array with coordinates of polygon

```
array([[726, 462],
       [724, 457],
       [723, 448],
...
```

I have need to scale polygon relative to the center of polygon for draw in OpenCV.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I found the center and for now I use a circle instead of a polygon. Lol. Give a hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the center of a polygon, refer to the formula here: [Algorithm for calculating polygon center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_polygon)

```
>>> def center(x, y):
...     diff = x[:-1] * y[1:] - x[1:] * y[:-1]
...     coef = 1 / (diff.sum() * 3)
...     return coef * ((x[:-1] + x[1:]) * diff).sum(), coef * ((y[:-1] + y[1:]) * diff).sum()
...
>>> a
array([[726, 462],
       [724, 457],
       [723, 448],
       [726, 462]])
>>> # Ensure that the position of the last point is the same as that of the first point.
>>> pos = np.array(center(*a.T))
>>> multiple = 2    # Zoom in twice
>>> new_a = (a - pos) * multiple + pos
```

I am not familiar with OpenCV, so I called the API of Matplotlib to draw:

[image]